# Exportación a Excel error con Inner Join

Tags: php, excel, join, phpexcel

Buenas tardes realizo un modulo `donde se pueda exportar lo que tiene mi tabla a un archivo de Excel mi tabla principal` equipos esta `compuesta por llaves foraneas`, esto quiere decir que se insertan por id's mas no por descripciones que las toma de las otras tablas. Así esta compuesta mi tabla equipos

```
id_equipo         PK
serial
marca
modelo
caracteristicas
ip_equipo        FK
mac_equipo       FK
id_tipo
id_estado        FK
id_estatus       FK
id_usuario       FK
id_ubicacion     FK
id_departamento  FK
```

`Mi código si me funciona y me exporta mis registros que tengo en mi tabla a un archivo de Excel`, pero como tengo claves foraneas y no las descripciones me `muestra numeros en vez de textos` `ya intente hacerlo con un INNER JOIN pero no me funciona`, este mismo INNER JOIN lo use para un reporte en PDF y funciona sin problema me muestra los textos que están almacenados en mis tablas foráneas.

Anexo mi codigo

Saludos

PHP DE EXCEL

```html
<?php

 require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
 require("connect_db.php");
 
 $sql = "SELECT id_equipo, serial, marca, modelo, caracteristicas, ip_equipo, mac_equipo, id_tipo, id_estado, id_estatus, id_usuario, id_ubicacion, id_departamento FROM equipos ";
 $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
 
 $fila = 2;
 
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel ();
 $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Codigos de programacion")->
 setDescription("Reporte de Equipos");
 
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Reporte_Trabajador");
 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('M')->setAutoSize(true);
 
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'ID Equipo');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'Serial');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'Marca');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'Modelo');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'Caracteristicas');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1', 'IP Equipo');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G1', 'MAC Equipo');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H1', 'Tipo Equipo');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I1', 'Estado Equipo');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J1', 'Estatus Equipo');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K1', 'Usuario Equipo');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L1', 'Ubicación');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M1', 'Departamento');
 
 
 while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
 {
  
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $row['id_equipo'] ); 
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$fila, $row['serial'] ); 
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $row['marca'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $row['modelo'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$fila, $row['caracteristicas'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$fila, $row['ip_equipo'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$fila, $row['mac_equipo'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$fila, $row['id_tipo'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$fila, $row['id_estado'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$fila, $row['id_estatus'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$fila, $row['id_usuario'] );
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$fila, $row['id_ubicacion'] ); 
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$fila, $row['id_departamento'] ); 
 
 $fila++;
 }


 header("Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
 header('Content-Disposition: attechment;filename="Reporte_Equipos.xlsx"');
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
 
 $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
 $objWriter->save('php://output');
 
 
?>
```

Inner Join

```html
$sql=("SELECT e.id_equipo, e.serial, e.marca, e.modelo, e.caracteristicas, e.ip_equipo, e.mac_equipo, t.descripcion, et.descripcion,  est.descripcion, u.nombre, ub.descripcion, dp.descripcion 
    FROM equipos e
    INNER JOIN tipo t ON t.id_tipo = e.id_tipo
    INNER JOIN estado et ON et.id_estado = e.id_estado
    INNER JOIN estatus est ON est.id_estatus = e.id_estatus
    INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.id_usuario = e.id_usuario
    INNER JOIN ubicacion ub ON ub.id_ubicacion = e.id_ubicacion
    INNER JOIN departamento dp ON dp.id_departamento = e.id_departamento order by id_equipo");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás poniéndole el valor a la celda de una columna que no viene en el nuevo select

Ejm:

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$fila, $row['id_tipo'] );`

En el nuevo select no viene una columna `id_tipo` en cambio viene `t.descripcion` y ya que muchas de las columnas que traes se llaman `descripcion` debes ponerle alias

Por ejm:

`SELECT
  e.id_equipo, e.serial, e.marca, e.modelo, e.caracteristicas, e.ip_equipo, e.mac_equipo,
  t.descripcion tipo_desc,
  et.descripcion estado_desc,
  est.descripcion estatus_desc,
  u.nombre usu_nombre,
  ub.descripcion ubic_desc,
  dp.descripcion dep_desc
FROM
  equipos e
INNER JOIN tipo t ON t.id_tipo = e.id_tipo
INNER JOIN estado et ON et.id_estado = e.id_estado
INNER JOIN estatus est ON est.id_estatus = e.id_estatus
INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.id_usuario = e.id_usuario
INNER JOIN ubicacion ub ON ub.id_ubicacion = e.id_ubicacion
INNER JOIN departamento dp ON dp.id_departamento = e.id_departamento
ORDER BY
  id_equipo`

Y luego en el loop:

```
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
{ 
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $row['id_equipo'] ); 
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$fila, $row['serial'] ); 
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $row['marca'] );
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $row['modelo'] );
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$fila, $row['caracteristicas'] );
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$fila, $row['ip_equipo'] );
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$fila, $row['mac_equipo'] );
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$fila, $row['tipo_desc'] );
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$fila, $row['estado_desc'] );
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$fila, $row['estatus_desc'] );
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$fila, $row['usu_nombre'] );
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$fila, $row['ubic_desc'] ); 
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$fila, $row['dep_desc'] ); 

  $fila++;
}
```

Espero haya quedado claro :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justamente lo que estaba buscando. Saludos :)